# Authentication failed against database server at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`, the provided database credentials for `name` are not valid

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel, planetscale

Im using planestscale with prisma on a next js app that I'am trying to host on vercel but it runs on localhost without any error but as soon as I go to depolyment I count this error Authentication failed against database server at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`, the provided database credentials for `name` are not valid.
I added the same env variable to vercel and Ihave the variable in an .env file

```
DATABASE_URL='mysql://<um>:<pw>Q@aws.connect.psdb.cloud/<db-name>?sslaccept=strict'
```

note: I replaced the placeholders

and this is my schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}
```

why does'nt it work the same in deployment

Comment: can you sure password is correct?

Answer (score 5):

It could be that you are pushing the .env file to github.

Check the email that is related to your Planetscale account, you'll most likely have a mail saying the account details have been revoked.

You can remove the .env file with `git rm .env --cached` and on the gitignore file make sure you have:

```
.env
.env.local  
.env.staging
```

before pushing it back to github.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and simply went to my PlanetScale dashboard > Settings > Passwords and created a new password by clicking the button.

This gave me something like this:

```
database: db_name
username: lksjdfhg98e9348jd
host: aws.connect.psdb.cloud
password: pscale_pw_lkjsfhdgjsdhfglsdf3839nl
```

After this, I copied the data and created a new environment variable like this with the new information:

```
DIRECT_DATABASE_URL="mysql://lksjdfhg98e9348jd:pscale_pw_lkjsfhdgjsdhfglsdf3839nl@aws.connect.psdb.cloud/db_name?sslaccept=strict"
```

Then I just simply ran `npx prisma db push` command and this was the output:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MySQL database "db_name" at "aws.connect.psdb.cloud"

The database is already in sync with the Prisma schema.

✔ Generated Prisma Client (v5.2.0) to ./node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@5.2.0_prisma@5.2.0/node_modu
les/@prisma/client in 59ms
```

And latest i want to share the output error that i was facing:

```
Error: P1000: Authentication failed against database server at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`, the provided database credentials for `lakjsdfhlakdf90s8f` are not valid.

Please make sure to provide valid database credentials for the database server at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`.
```

*I hope this helps to somebody!*

Answer (score 1):

It Might be Helpful to just create a new password on PlanetScale.
Just click on "Get Connection Strings" on the Overview Tab , then "new password" > "create password" , then make sure you copy that connection string into your .env file, Make sure .env is written on .gitignore and try again!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah i had the same error but i resolved mine by updating the env variable on vercel after changing it on planet scale.
https://vercel.com/docs/projects/environment-variables